# How can I use Apache Continuum, Maven and Git (github) together?

Tags: java, git, maven, continuous-integration, continuum

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and still can't make this integration happen. I'm probabilly missing something really simple here and got confused along the way!

First of all, how can I successfull host a Maven project on github, so that when I run the command mvn build (or release, not sure which) it checks in my changes to the github repository, if the build runs successfully?

Second question: after the first integration is done, how can I get Continuum to watch for the changes I push and build the remote repository to check if the tests are still passing?

If the flow I'm trying to achieve is wrong, please tell me what would be the best way to get these 3 tools running together. :)

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to distinguish, what those tools are for.

*Continuum* is an application for continous integration, i.e. when configured it watches a certain repository and after every commit it runs build task.

*Maven* is a tool to build your project, run tests, generate artifacts, etc. It doesn't know anything about git or continuum.

*Git* is a tool to store your changes in repository.

So for these tools, Maven and Git don't depend on each other and not aware of each other. They're base.
Continuum can work on top of those two, it takes git repository you provide him, and runs build according to maven pom you provide him.

Regarding your words:
`so that when I run the command mvn build (or release, not sure which) it checks in my changes to the github repository, if the build runs successfully?`

It doesn't make sense, because build and tests may take an hours to complete. While git commit is quite a common operation.

Continuum is more to ensure the stability of the build. So if you want to deploy a build somewhere, you check if it's green. Or if it became red, you go and fix it, because appliation build from repository should be always green.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, I have this very basic project using Maven, and I want to use Continuum, it forces me to provide a scm tool, then I decided to use git (because I already had a little experience with it).
But I cant figure out how to get it working, and it is hard to find material explaining how to do this. Most people seem to use svn instead, and I have never used it.